# shoulda-matchers are not matching

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-6, shoulda-matchers

I am creating a TextMessage model to manage communications.
I am using [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers)' for testing

my model

```
class TextMessage < ApplicationRecord
  validates :message, presence: true
end
```

Now my test

```
RSpec.describe TextMessage, type: :model do
  subject { FactoryBot.create(:text_message) }
  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of :message }
end
```

I am able to run FactoryBot.create(:text_message) on the console to create a text message without any problems. But when I run my test sweet I get this error

```
TextMessage
  is expected to validate that :message cannot be empty/falsy (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) TextMessage is expected to validate that :message cannot be empty/falsy
     Failure/Error: self.message = message.gsub("\u0000", '')

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Can you show your text_message factory, please? And the stack trace of the error, where is the `self.message = message.gsub("\u0000", '')` line?

Comment: Works For Me™. You probably have something that normalizes attributes which is trying to strip null bytes.

Comment: @Schwern Thanks you so much.  I was able to change `self.message = message.gsub("\u0000", '')` to `self.message = message.to_s.gsub("\u0000", '')` this maked the test pass

Comment: That will change a `nil` into an empty string which may be important. To avoid altering the data in unexpected ways use [the safe navigation operator `&.`](https://rubyinrails.com/2017/11/17/safe-navigation-operator-ampersand-dot-in-ruby/). `self.message = message&.gsub("\u0000", '')`.

Comment: Thanks I will do that change